# Retrieving a Pg Number from a PDF document

Tags: python, regex, pdf

I'm quite new to Python and I want to run a search for a keyword, and find out the page number.

If I know the pg number I can extract the associated table from camelot easily.. however finding the page number is the tricky part! Any suggestions?

Comment: You should include some code and explain which part you are having trouble with so that someone can help. There is not enough information in this post to understand what the code issue is.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32430728/python-extract-text-from-pdf-page-wise-to-list ?
Btw welcome to SO, read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score -2):

You can modify the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32430728/python-extract-text-from-pdf-page-wise-to-list) to parse pdf pagewise and return the page number if the keyword matches with the content of the page and go further from that.

your Keyword allthough has to be somewhat unique in that document to reliably identify the correct page number